# Pass through string in link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, html

This should be simple and I'm sure it is for you. I'm a Rails and jQuery newbie reading the Rails API for link_to and it suggests html_options = {} but there is no example I could find. Below is the html I want to end up because I want to use a jquery plugin for a modal dialog box for a contact form (if there is an easier Rails way, I'm happy to hear):

```
 <a href="http://mywebsite.com/contact-us.html" name="box" class="close-reveal-modal" data-reveal-id="myModal">Get more info.</a>
```

Based on my reading of the api, this is my best guess but it fails:

```
 <%= link_to 'Get more info', contact_us_path, :class => 'close-reveal-modal', html_options = {"data-reveal-id = 'myModal'"} %>
```

Yanking out the html_options section works, but without the call to the plugin. What I get are errors about missing closing parens, but that doesn't make sense because everything is closed. Am I misunderstanding html_options?, sam

Comment: Your `html_options` hash is a little funny.  Try `{'data-reveal-id' => 'myModal'}` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't even need `html_options` at all. Rails 3 supports a `data` option that accepts a hash and turns that hash into individual `data-*` attributes:

```
<%= link_to 'Get more info', contact_us_path, :class => 'close-reveal-modal', :data => { :reveal_id => 'myModal' } %>
```

The docs for that option are actually on the [`ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper#tag` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ruby hash in options. ERB code may look like this

```
<%= link_to 'Get more info', contact_us_path, :class => 'close-reveal-modal', :data => { 'reveal-id' => 'myModal'} %>
```

Comment: How did I miss that in the Rails API? I still cannot find that :data is documented? thx.